# VSTO vs. Primary Interop Assemblies, what's the difference?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, vsto, ms-office

I already developed a large Office application-level add-in and it works like a charm, but I have problems understanding the technical basis.

1. So what exactly are **VSTO** and the **PIAs** good for?
2. Does **VSTO** just provide a proper *project type* for Visual Studio and that's it?
3. Are the **Primary Interop Assemblies** (PIA) just some kind of wrapper for accessing the *Office Object Model*?
4. Do both of them provide more things and features than I am aware of?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[VSTO is the application runtime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb608603.aspx) that provides hooks (*solution loader*) into the Office subsystem via PIA. [PIAs are wrappers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/15s06t57) around the unmanaged COM API (`IDTExtensibility2`) that Office is built from. PIAs provide managed access and run above the VSTO runtime.

VSTO comes with project types that build the [deployment manifest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb771323) required for detecting dependencies and loading your Add-In at runtime.

The [PIAs provide managed access](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb771305) to the COM object-model, but it also [supports unmanaged access](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa942114) should you want more control over how your solution is loaded (*hence you always have VSTO runtime, but not always PIAs*).

This [MSDN link provides a great overview of the evolution of PIAs and VSTO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa537182.aspx) away from [`IDtExtensibility2`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/extensibility.idtextensibility2%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) which is another loading option (*outside of PIAs*)

Comment: @SilverNinja does VSTO require PIA installation?

Comment: If you are using VSTO 2010 you don't need to install the PIAs. By default, the [interop types are embedded in your add-in assembly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee317478.aspx). You can toggle this behavior by changing the **Embed Interop Types** flag for each office assembly you include.

Comment: Thanks for confirming SilverNinja. I thought this was the case. I see the interops embedded in an add-in. I just need to make sure all other assemblies have the Embed Interop Types flag set.

Comment: it is also worth pointing out that VSTO is an optional level above PIA (for those amongst us using VS Express editions), that makes things easier but is not necessary. :)

Comment: Nice answer, but how to understand "PIAs provide managed access and run above the VSTO runtime" ? The VSTO uses PIA to communicate with the COM Objects in office