# VSTO fatal error System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC'

Tags: .net, excel, vb.net, vsto, office-addins

### I have used
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop and Reference of Microsoft excel is added to project/solution

Following are declaration

```
 Public xlsfilepath As String
 Public oxlsapp As New Excel.Application
 Public oxlsworkbook As Excel.Workbook
 Public oxlsworksheet As Excel.Worksheet
 Public oxlcellsrange As Excel.Range
 Dim xchar As String
```

---

### Cell reading process from existing file

```
oxlcellsrange = oxlsworksheet.Cells(iRow, iCol)
MessageBox.Show(oxlsworksheet.Range(oxlcellsrange).Value)<----Here gives fatal error
```

**System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC'**

### Don't understand why?

Image is attached for that describes more.

[image: Error message]

Answer (score 0):

> Reference of Microsoft excel is added to project/solution.

There's a confusing thing about Office Development. You need to reference the Private Interop Assemblies [VSTO vs. Primary Interop Assemblies, what's the difference?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10914615/495455)

You might have mistakenly referenced the COM references and they're only supposed to be used in for UnitTesting Mocks of Office:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/47256597/495455

Answer (score 0):

Excel COM references were set up correctly due to the fact that previous lines of code are working without errors. Moreover, that is a runtime error.

This is a widely-spread error when dealing with the Excel object model. You may find a similar posts like [Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12714626/exception-from-hresult-0x800a03ec-error) popular.

The [Worksheet.Range](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.range) property accepts a string that is a range reference when one argument is used. Either a string that is a range reference or a Range object when two arguments are used. For example:

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value = 3.14159
```

Answer (score 0):

I perform following steps and my error gone/resolved

1-Run > type > dcomcnfg > it open component service window (as administrator)

In that window

2-Go to Component service > Computers > MyComputer > DCOM Config

3-All services will list

4-select Microsoft Excel in the list and right click on it.

5-In property window go to > identity TAB

6-I selected The Launching User Radio Button and Applied it.

7-Then My Error resolved.

but it amuse me.